# How to get subset of matrix where first column is any of a list

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix called `LungData` with gene names and patient samples. There are ~26,000 genes and for each gene there are 41 samples. The gene names are in the first column, and the samples in the subsequent columns.

```
> dim(LungData)
[1] 26002    42
```

I have a subset of ~2,000 genes that I'm interested in. This subset is a list called `GeneSubset`.

```
> dim(GeneSubset)
[1] 1999    1
```

How can I get the 2000x42 sub-matrix which only contains the genes from `GeneSubset`? I'm not interested in the other genes, and dealing with a smaller sub-matrix will make the computations go a lot faster.

Comment: Please show few lines of  small example data and expected output.  Try `match` or `%in%`  `LungData[LungData[,1] %in% GeneSubset[,1],]`

Answer (score 1):

We can use either `%in%` or `match`.  If the first column of 'LungData' is the 'genenames' and the dataset is a matrix, we use `%in%` to get a logical vector of TRUE/FALSE by comparing with 'GeneSubset' and this can be used for filtering the rows of 'LungData'.

```
 LungData[LungData[,1] %in% GeneSubset[,1],]
```

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer.

Answer (score 0):

Store the subset of desired genes in a vector instead of a list.

```
GeneSubset <- as.vector(GeneSubset)
```

Also,

```
rownames(LungData) <- LungData[,1] #assigning row names to the original matrix
LungData <- LungData[,-1] #removing 1st column since we already assigned rownames
ReqdData <- LungData[GeneSubset,] #subsetting the data on the basis of rownames
```

You might also want to use the subset function in base R or the code given by @akrun.